# Referencing subitems without having subitems as items

Tags: graphics, hyperref, cross-referencing

what I'm trying to do is referencing `subcaptions` / `subfloats`, but without having sub elements.

Ok from scratch.

Usually you add a `label` to every element you want to reference. e.g. like this:

```
\begin{figure} [h]
  \subfloat[]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]
     {example-image-a}\label{f1a}}
  \subfloat[text 2]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]
     {example-image-b}\label{f1b}}
  \subfloat[]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]
     {example-image-c}\label{f1c}}

  \captionof{figure}[]{long text 1}
  \label{f1all}
\end{figure}
```

which you can reference like this:

```
See fig~\ref{f1a}, fig~\ref{f1b} and fig~\ref{f1c}.
```

working fine and displaying something like this (if `\usepackage{hyperref}` is used):

[image]

---

But I have a case where the image file itself holds different "sub"-images (which cannot get splitted for various resons), but on the image there is already text like `(a)`,`(b)` and `(c)`. I want to reference it in a similar way as for the example above. Eg. with this code:

```
\begin{figure} [h]
  \subfloat{
     \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]
     {example-image}}

  \captionof{figure}[]{long text 2}
  \label{f2}
\end{figure}
```

and a reference like this:

```
See fig~\ref{f2}a, fig~\ref{f2}b and fig~\ref{f2}c.
```

Of cause the letters are not included in the linkbox (due to they are not in the `\ref` tag) looking like this:

[image]

---

**My question now:** Is there a way to add the letter to the linked text as well that no one will see the difference? (Of cause the link target should just be anywhere in the image [like the normal behaviour] and should not be different for any letter.)

---

Here my full working MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [h]
  \subfloat[]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]
     {example-image-a}\label{f1a}}
  \subfloat[text 2]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]
     {example-image-b}\label{f1b}}
  \subfloat[]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]
     {example-image-c}\label{f1c}}

  \captionof{figure}[]{long text 1}
  \label{f1all}
\end{figure}

Referencing in the text like: See fig~\ref{f1a}, fig~\ref{f1b} and fig~\ref{f1c}.



\begin{figure} [h]
  \subfloat{
     \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]
     {example-image}}

  \captionof{figure}[]{long text 2}
  \label{f2}
\end{figure}

Referencing in the text like: See fig~\ref{f2}a, fig~\ref{f2}b and fig~\ref{f2}c.


\end{document}
```

Comment: You could change the highlighting of links with hyperrefs settings to be coloured text and change the colour of the letter to be the same (just as a quick idea). Or you place several labels after you `\refstepcounter` a fake counter which has the formatting `\renewcommand{\thefakecounter}{\arabic{figure}\alph{fakecounter}}`.

Comment: @Skillmon wow I haven't thought about this. But your totally right. In my proper code its anyways just a coloured text (not a box). thx

Comment: (i) Why you use  `\captionof{figure}{...}` in figure environment? (ii) What is wrong if reference consider subcaption? (iii) @Skillmon was faster for third comment :)

Comment: This (my first idea) might have the downside of not being clickable in your PDF-viewer, so could lead to confusion, because the number is clickable, but not the letter.

Comment: @Zarko `i:` good question ;) `ii:` what do you mean? there are no subelements where I can add a label to?! for referencing I need the letters because I will explain in the text what is displayed on (a), (b) ...

Comment: (i) in `figure` environment normaly is used `\caption[<short caption, if exist>]{<long caption>}` (ii) one `subfigure` in figure is, sorry , nonsense. if you have more sub figures in figure, than you put labels in `subfloat` environments as you do in the first figure in your MWE. Obviously I don't understand your intention.

Comment: thx for asking. Yes I know a subfloat makes no sense using just one image. It's just to show the similarity to the first example. My intension was to have multiple labels (for referencing not as captions) for just one single image. And due to `\ref` adds letters to the image number when having multiple images (in a `figure` sorounding) I want to have the same effect (due to the letters are printed on the image [not latex text]). Like the outcome in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using my second approach with the fakecounter, you could create what you need with this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{fakecounter}[figure]
\renewcommand*{\thefakecounter}{\thefigure\alph{fakecounter}}
\newcommand*\sublabel[1]{\refstepcounter{fakecounter}\label{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure} [h]
  \subfloat{
     \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]
     {example-image}}

  \caption[]{long text 2}
  \label{f2}
  \sublabel{f2a}
  \sublabel{f2b}
  \sublabel{f2c}
\end{figure}

Also see fig~\ref{f2a}, fig~\ref{f2b} and fig~\ref{f2c}.

\begin{figure} [h]
  \subfloat{
     \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]
     {example-image}}

  \caption[]{long text 2}
  \label{f3}
  \sublabel{f3a}
  \sublabel{f3b}
  \sublabel{f3c}
\end{figure}

Also see fig~\ref{f3a}, fig~\ref{f3b} and fig~\ref{f3c}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: oh wow. Didn't know this was possible. I believe that would be the easiest approach (code readability wise). thx

Comment: just a minor suggestion. I added the `\sublabel` directly after `\subfloat{` due to clicking on the reference will then show the image. Adding the labels below the caption will jump below the figure (figure not visible) ;)

Comment: @user2798895 you have to put it after `\caption` as otherwise the `figure`-counter wouldn't have the correct state. Try it with the minimal example from my answer. On the first `figure` you'd get 'fig 0a' as output from the `\ref`s. The counter is increased by the `\caption` command not by `\begin{figure}`. Also the `fakecounter` gets reset after the `figure`-counter is increased, adding `\sublabel` before `\caption` might result in incorrect state of `fakecounter` resulting in stuff like 'fig 1d'.

Comment: And just to make it clear: The same is true if you'd put `\sublabel` in a `\subfloat`. `\subfloat` increases the figure counter used in labels in a way that doesn't reset the `fakecounter`. Because of this, you will get wrong letters appended (putting one `\sublabel` in the second figures `\subfloat` results in 'fig 2d' instead of 'fig 2a'). You really have to use it after `\caption`.